# Javascript save data in objects or array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am making a drag and drop tool in javascript. 
I have a collection of images that I can drag and drop into a grid. This grid has 3 rows and 20 columns.

When an image is dragged onto the grid I want to save this data. For example I drag image and drop it on row 1, column 2. How can I save this data in javascript ?

In php this would be:

```
<?php
// row 1, column 2
$savedItems[1][2] = array("image" => "testimage.jpg", "extra" => 1);

?>
```

This way I can check if there is already an image on that spot or not. Or if I want to change the options of the spot I can search in the $savedItems array.

But how could I save this data in javascript? So it is easy to add and search data in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost exactly the same in JavaScript.

```
var cells = [ [ ], [ ], [ ] ];

function insertImage(row, column, image) {
  if (cells[row][column]) {
    console.info('Already exists!');
    return false;
  } else {
    cells[row][column] = image;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are performing a drag drop , you must be knowing the index of row and column into which you are dropping.
When  you perform a drag Drop , call a function like saveValues(rowIndex, columnIndex , value) to save your values at that location into array. Before saving , check whether the location already has some data other than your default values. If yes do not save values and break so that drag drop will not be performed , else save the values and and then perform drag drop.

Let us assume your array is named as :  dragDropGrid

```
    function saveValues(rowIndex, columnIndex , value) {

    // value here is something related to that image .

    var valueAtIndex = dragDropGrid[rowIndex][columnIndex] ;

      if(valueAtIndex != null || valueAtIndex != "" || valueAtIndex != undefined ) {

         // If there already exists a value

         return false; // something to break the drag drop


     }else{ // if array location is empty

       dragDropGrid[rowIndex][columnIndex] = value;  //saved value at that index.

     return true; // now call drag drop.
    }

  }
```

You can either directly call this function on some event  after performing  dragDrop . Make sure function returns properly so as to continue or break the drag drop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can print the $savedItems as a javascript global variable.

```
<?php
echo '<script>';
echo 'var saved_items = ' . json_encode($savedItems); . ';';
echo '</script>';
```